# for-loop: necessity of pointer variable as condition in if-statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

I dont understand why the condition of if-statement needs to be a pointer. I assumed a normal variable call will not give any complaints.

Was trying to learn about std::vector::erase from cppreference, got intrigued about the example there (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> c{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    for (auto &i : c) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    // Erase all even numbers (C++11 and later)
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ) {
        if (*it % 2 == 0) {
            it = c.erase(it); // THE LINE ABOVE THIS
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    for (auto &i : c) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```

Hope anyone could share an explanation or direct me to an available resource.

Comment: Its not a pointer.  It is de-referencing the  iterator to get the value stored in that location in the vector.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That's not a range loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ranged based for-loop: necessity of pointer variable as condition in
>   if-statement

I think that the confusion is that you are incorrectly considering the ordinary for-loop

```
for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); )
```

as the ranged for-loop.

In your program the range-based for loop is used only to output the vector.

```
for (auto &i : c) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Iterators behave as pointers. That is for them for example there are defined `operator *` and `operator ++`.

Consider a similar program that deals with an array. Of course you can not remove elements from an array but you can move "removed" elements to the end of the array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + N; ++p )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    int *q = a;

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + N; ++p )
    {
        if ( not ( *p % 2 == 0  ) )
        {
            if ( p != q ) *q = *p;
            ++q;
        }
    }

    for ( const int *p = a; p != q; ++p )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```

As you can see in this if statement

```
if ( not ( *p % 2 == 0  ) )
```

you have to dereference the pointer to get the value pointed to by the pointer.

Now rewrite the program the following way using generic functions `std::begin`, `std::cbegin`, and `std::cend`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( auto p = std::cbegin( a ); p != std::cend( a ); ++p )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto q = std::begin( a );

    for ( auto p = std::cbegin( a ); p != std::end( a ); ++p )
    {
        if ( not ( *p % 2 == 0  ) )
        {
            if ( p != q ) *q = *p;
            ++q;
        }
    }

    for (  auto p = std::begin( a ); p != q; ++p )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Now the pointers look like iterators and nothing was changed in the if statement

```
if ( not ( *p % 2 == 0  ) )
```

Comment: thank you Vlad, the demo really got me thinking about whats referencing / dereferencing / pointing what, so array (a) became 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. and pointer/iterator q is at '5'

Answer (score 3):

In the classical loop:

`auto it = c.begin()` - `it` is an *iterator*. To access what it refers to you need to dereference it, which you do with `*it`. The `*` there does not mean *pointer*, it means *dereference* (technically, on iterators, it's a call to `operator*`).

See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator

In the range based loop:

`for (auto &i : c)` - here you get back a reference to the element in the container directly. No iterators involved.

Comment: Technically `operator*` which on iterators means something different.

Comment: @tadman - Right. Good point. Answer updated.